# I am trying to access a specific row but I am having an error in Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: snapShotChnaged.forEach is not a function`. I need a specific row, that's why I am using the doc.

```
getAllDonations() {
    firestore
      .collection('donations')
      .doc(this.$route.params.id)
      .onSnapshot((snapShotChnaged) => {
          this.donations = []
          snapShotChnaged.forEach((donationDoc) => {
              this.donations.push({
                  id: donationDoc.id,
                  name: donationDoc.data().name,
                  surname: donationDoc.data().surname,
                  class: donationDoc.data().class,
                  amount: donationDoc.data().amount
              })
          });
      });
},
```

Comment: If you console log `snapShotChnaged` what do you get?

Comment: bulky data @Daniel_Knights the thing is that if remove .doc(this.$route.params.id) it will work but it will show me the whole data of all array i just want that specific id

Comment: If `snapShotChnaged` isn't an array, you can't use `forEach`

Comment: :O really so how can i fetch data if i dont push it into an array

Comment: What *is* returned? If it's an object, you can still loop over it, but you'll have to use a different method

Comment: no its not an object im just passing the id from one component to another

Comment: should probably create a new question rather than editing this one

Comment: @JeremyWarren Please don't change the entire content and title of your question => the provided answers do not make any sense anymore. If you think your question is not valid anymore, delete it. IMHO it is a valid question and it could help others in the future, if they mixup the use of `onSnaphot()` between `DocumentReference` and `CollectionReference` => I've therefore set it back to the last edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference):     (`firestore.collection('donations').doc()`) and therefore there is no `forEach()` method for the `DocumentSnapshot` (i.e. your `snapShotChnaged` object).

One would use `forEach()` on the `querySnapshot` returned by `onSnapshot()` for `CollectionReference`s.

You need to do as follows:

```
firestore
  .collection('donations')
  .doc(this.$route.params.id)
     .onSnapshot(doc => {
        const docData = doc.data());
        // ....
  });
```

Comment: Hey @RenaudTarnec thanks for your feedback I am tying to use foreach on docData

Comment: @Renauld thanks for your feedback I am trying to use foreach on docData such as docData.foreach but its stil giving me error

Comment: This is because docData is a simple [JavaScript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) which does not have a `forEach()` method. Use one of the methods detailed in this doc, e.g. `values()`or `entries()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `forEach` method on `DocumentSnapshot` which does not have `foreEach` method like query snapshot. check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)

if you are planning to iterate through all the items in the **donations** collection you can change your code as follows.

```
getAllDonations() {
  firestore
    .collection('donations')
    .onSnapshot((snapShotChnaged) => {
        this.donations = []
        snapShotChnaged.forEach((donationDoc) => {
            this.donations.push({
                id: donationDoc.id,
                name: donationDoc.data().name,
                surname: donationDoc.data().surname,
                class: donationDoc.data().class,
                amount: donationDoc.data().amount
            })
        });
    });
},
```